# Replacing default texts to custom ones in all pages

Tags: angular

I'm building an app using Angular 8 (JHipster) and I created a page where the user can define a string to be replaced by a custom one:

[image: custom text insert]

I want the occurrences of "This is the default text" to be replaced by "This is my custom text" on all pages (components) of the app. I don't want to add a method on every place I'm using this default text. For example, I don't want to do this on my template:

```
<p>getCustomText("This is the default text")</p>
```

I'm thinking something something that works without having to individually treat each string in the source code. Maybe a method called everytime a page is rendered, so I can read the template and return a new template with my custom strings, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an attribute directive and adding it to app-component. Inside the directive read the innerHTML and replace the required text.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Pipe. If don't know what a Pipe is, take a look at https://angular.io/guide/pipes.

I recommand generating a "customText" pipe inside a *SharedModule* (`ng generate module shared` then `ng generate pipe shared/customText`). Then export the Pipe and import your SharedModule in every Module that will need it. To learn more about SharedModule take a look at https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules.

For your customText Pipe logic, it's up to you but you will certainly need a service that will manage the default value as you may need to store/retrieve/update it (through database or whatever storage)

```js
// shared.module.ts

@NgModule({
  exports: [CustomTextPipe],
  declarations: [CustomTextPipe]
})
export class SharedModule {}



// custom-text.pipe.ts

@Pipe({
  name: 'customText',
})
export class CustomTextPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
    private defaultTextService: DefaultTextService
  ) {}

  transform(text?: string): string {
    // I don't know what you need but maybe something like this
    return this.defaultTextService.replace(text)
  }
}


// some module that need the pipe

@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [
    // other modules...
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule {}
```

The pipe in action

```html
<p>{{ "This is the default text" | customText }}</p>
```

Comment: As I said, it is infeasible to have to explicitly call a method or a pipe for each piece of text in the system. It would have to be something more general, like a filter that receives the template and returns it with the replaced texts.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want something parsing your whole project on runtime. If it's the case then do not use angular but a cms.